# How to close window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `UserControl userControl1` with button.
When user click button i create new `UserControl` and show it:

```
private void Button_UserControl1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{                                           
    Window window = new Window
    {
        Title = "Control2",
        Content = _control2

    };
    _control2= new UserControl2(ref window);
    window.ShowDialog();
}
```

at `UserControl2` when i desides to close myself (control2 window) (another button click):

```
private void btOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{          
    _parent.Close();  //_parent is ref window
}
```

But i can not close it!

Can you tell me: how to close created window (`control2`) by clicking to button on `control2`?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand how your code is meant to work. What is the value of `_control2` at the time you create `window`? You assign a new `UserControl2` to `_control2` _afterwards_, but that won't change the `Content` of `window`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should close the parent window:

```
private void btOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{          
    Window.GetWindow(this).Close();
}
```

This way you don't need to have reference to the parent. GetWindow will always return the window that is hosting the UserControl.